# Buddypress - Custom Name For Logged In User's Messages In Message Thread

Tags: buddypress

How to change the name of the user viewing a message thread (you) to something like "You said" or "You replied"

So the thread would look like..

> **Susan** - *january 17, 2016*
>
> I too am fine
>
> **You Said** - *january 16, 2016*
>
> I am fine, thank you. How are you?
>
> **Susan** - *january 15, 2016*
>
> Hi there, how are you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A. in the template file only..**

in message.php replace

```
<?php bp_the_thread_message_sender_name(); ?>
```

with

```
<?php 
$userID = bp_loggedin_user_id();
$senderID = bp_get_the_thread_message_sender_id();
if ($userID == $senderID) : ?>
    You wrote:
<?php else : ?>
    <?php bp_the_thread_message_sender_name(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**B. or, as a function**

add this to bp-custom.php

```
function custom_bp_the_thread_message_sender_name() {
$userID = bp_loggedin_user_id();
$senderID = bp_get_the_thread_message_sender_id();
    if ($userID == $senderID) {
        echo 'You wrote';
    }
    else {
        bp_the_thread_message_sender_name();
    }
}
```

in message.php replace

```
<?php bp_the_thread_message_sender_name(); ?>
```

with

```
<?php custom_bp_the_thread_message_sender_name(); ?>
```

There will be three instances of `bp_the_thread_message_sender_name()`, I wouldn't bother with the title="" one.